# correlation and independence: common mistake?

Tags: correlation, independence, linear, pearson-r

Almost everywhere I read

*If the variables are independent, Pearson's correlation coefficient is 0*

I understand that correlation gives information only for **linear dependence/independence** variables and, if the two values are **linearly** independent, then their correlation is zero.
Instead, the term **independent** is often used as **statistical** independence (also in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence where in correspondence of *independence* there is a link to *statistical independence*) but *linear* independence is not the same of *statistical* independence (*statistical* ind. $\implies$ *linear* ind. but not but not vice versa) so, is there a common error (also in wikipedia) or something is not clear to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"If two variables are independent, their correlation is 0" is correct, at least except for random correlation. That is, the correlation won't be *exactly* 0 and, in 5% of the cases, it will be significantly different (at 5%) from 0, but it is 0 in the population.

However "if two variables have correlation 0, they are independent" is not necessarily correct, as they could depend on each other in a nonlinear way.

"Independence" includes "no linear relationship" as well as "no quadratic relationship", "no cubic relationship" etc.

Comment: By not stating explicitly whether you are talking about *data* or *random variables* here, this post is potentially quite confusing and could be misread by many.  You seem to have in mind the former, but the concept of "independent" applies only to the latter.